# What does this sort of method signature mean -> public partial class Entities : Entity.ObjectContext<Entities>

Tags: c#, .net

What does this sort of method signature mean

```
public partial class Entities : Entity.ObjectContext<Entities>
```

I know anything after the colon (:) is inherits from, but what does the

```
<Entities>
```

mean?

Is it some sort of generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a method signature, but a ([partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)) class declaration.

"partial" signals that the rest of the class may be defined in one or more separate files.  Partial classes are particularly useful when doing code generation (they are used for example by the WinForms designer to separate generated code from user code).  The specific example you show is from Entity Framework.

The `<Entities>` part means that this is a [Generic function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Doh, yeah, saying method was me typing the question out hastily. Thanks for the pointer to the Generic function, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: `one or more separate files` -- it should be zero or more separate files.  You don't *need* to have two different declarations, you can have just one.

Comment: It's not a generic function, it's a generic class.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah... *may* be defined on one or more separate files ;-)  I meant to connote that separate files are not *required*.